# Recommended strategy for having a page (already made from a master) dynamically load content within it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to build an Admin page that already uses the same Master the rest of my site does. Within this Admin page, I have a sidebar with links for different things that an Admin user needs to do. I want those links to load HTML/Razor content in the center of the page but I want to not make separate Admin pages for each bit of functionality.

What strategy or process would work best for this situation? Every search result I'm finding seems to be just learning about how to make a simple Master, but I don't want to make multiple Masters for my site.

(I'm very new to all this, but I learn fast from examples and references.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem from dynamically change the UI by fetching from server through Ajax calls to Simple tabs.

As you said you are new to this you can use [tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)